# Просмотр отдельной новости из listView на Android

Tags: android, парсер

Всем привет, делаю значит я диплом, он собой представляет некий портал, как для студента, так и для абитуриентов.

Суть проблемы в следующем: есть у меня раздел "Новости", получаю новости путем парсинга html страницы вуза с новостями, затем они добавляются в `listView`.

Вот что мне интересно, как сделать так, чтобы по нажатии на какую-то из новостей у меня осуществлялся переход на другой фрагмент с более детальной информацией по этой новости?

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: разбейте ваш вопрос на более мелкие проблемы: 1. *Как совершить действие по клику на элемент списка* 2. *Как открыть новый фрагмент* 3. *Как достать из списка данные, соответствующие элементу, по которому был произведен клик*. Теперь решайте эти вопросы отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам нужно создать событие `OnItemClickListener` типо так

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){

    ItemClicked item = adapter.getItem(position);

    // тут destinationActivity это куда проходит
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,destinationActivity.class);

    // тут будет переход на ваш фрагмент или активити
    startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```